# I want to query the row values as Column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, reporting-services

I have a query to result in the below data from DB

[image]

But actually, I want to get the data as

[image]

Is there any way we can do this the SSRS?
How can I do this? really stuck

Comment: SSRS is not generally used with mysql and did you read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Maybe you are using `SQL Server` and not `MySQL` ? In `SQL Server` is quite easy because you can use [PIVOT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in SSRS without changing your dataset.

1. Add a Matrix control to your report
2. Drag the Assignee field to the `Rows` placeholder
3. Drag the Priority_n field to the `Columns` placeholder
4. Drag the Count_C field to the `Data` placeholder

that's it. If this does not help, let me know and I will update with sample images.

Comment: Wow. Really my life saver.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem could you please mark it as accepted (the check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons). This will help others find answers to similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck the column names;

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [Assignee],
    [Priority_n],
    [Count_C]
  FROM dataset
) Results
PIVOT (
  SUM([Count_C])
  FOR [Priority_n]
  IN (
    [High],
    [Medium],
    [Low]
  )
) AS PivotTable
```